# Swagger change base URL in Python using flasgger library

Tags: python, rest, flask, flasgger

I am trying to update my Swagger Base URL from '/' to '/testapp' for my REST API

This is my Swagger Config

```
swagger_config = {
    "headers": [
    ],
    "specs": [
        {
            "endpoint": 'APISpecification',
            "route": '/APISpecification',
            "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
            "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
        }
    ],
    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    "specs_route": "/swagger_doc/",
}
```

As per the config, I can access the Swagger Page at `127.0.0.1:4444/swagger_doc`

I want to change it to `127.0.0.1:4444/testapp/swagger_doc`

I have tried using `basePath` as `/testapp` in this config. Did not work.

Issue is `127.0.0.1:4444/swagger_doc` needs some .js and .css files which are inside `127.0.0.1:4444/flasgger_static/` which should change to `127.0.0.1:4444/testapp/flasgger_static/`.

Comment: have you tried adding `url_prefix` config option ?

Answer (score 3):

You should add `"url_prefix": "/testapp"` in `swagger_config`.

```py
swagger_config = {
    "headers": [
    ],
    "specs": [
        {
            "endpoint": 'APISpecification',
            "route": '/APISpecification',
            "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
            "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
        }
    ],
    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    "specs_route": "/swagger_doc/",
    "url_prefix": "/testapp"
}
```